# Can't find file when using windeployqt.exe

Tags: windows, qt

I'm pretty sure this isn't how I'm supposed to use windeployqt, but I have an executable which is missing some dependencies (specifically the qt plugin windows). I thought I could use the windeployqt tool in order to find the missing dependencies for this executable and install them, but I get a "does not exist" error when I try and run the following:

`windeployqt.exe ExecutableFileName.exe`
I tried this after trying the full path (e.g. `windeployqt.exe pathtoexecutablefile\executablefilename.exe`
but both times I get two errors. Either filename.exe does not exist, or pathtofile\filename.exe doesn't exist. Is there a way to fix this or am I using the tool wrong? I've added the folder containing the tool to my system path, but do I need to add the folder containing the executable as well?

Comment: You need to set up your build environment before invoking windeployqt. If your software is built with any MSVC kits, you need to call a specific batch file ("vcvars.bat" or alike, installed by Visual Studio) before invoking windeployqt. Your application does not need to be in the system path, and it should work from any directory (using absolute paths). Note that absolute paths on windows use backward slashes and always start with the drive-letter (or multiple slashes if using the device-name).

Comment: is there an easy way to check if it is built with MSVC kits considering I don't have access to the original installer and it was never officially released online so there's no documentation?

Comment: wait what? you cant simply use windeployqt on not-your-own-software. windeployqt is part of a Qt-environment. unless you know the **exact** environment, and have the **exact** same Qt-libraries as the original author of your .exe file, this will never work

Comment: Yeah I thought this might be the case. That's a shame, thanks for your help.

Comment: Well its not the end of the world, windeployqt doesnt do anything that you couldnt do manually. It just copies the Qt-libs (from the same location where windeployqt.exe resides) to the target directory. You could do that yourself. But whether your application will work with your Qt libraries, you'll have to test. Maybe you're lucky and the original author used the same Qt version as you have, and didnt modify it in any way. Then it could work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go...